# Punctuation confusion, commas, semicolons, and em dashes

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons, em-dashes

I'm having a hard time trying to punctuate the following sentence.  I have it using just commas right now, but I do not think that is right.

> On Earth they see the Sun every day, it’s always there, from when they are born till when they die.

Or how about:

> On Earth they see the Sun every day; it’s always there--from when they are born till when they die.

Also, does example 1 bring any confusion? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: By `their` you most definitely mean `they're`, right?

Comment: **"On Earth they see the Sun every day. It’s always there—from when they're born till when they die."** I'd also recommend replacing your `when`s with `the time`.